# Xpath - trying to get all li objects that not under a specific div.

Tags: xpath, rvest

I'm trying to get from the following page:
https://ideas.repec.org/a/aea/aecrev/v92y2002i3p411-433.html
The list of references.

In order to so I try to grab all the "li" elements under the div "references-body".

As you can see there are some cases where there the list includes older versions or other versions of the references. I don't want to get those.

I'm using the following code - but it doesn't seem to be working 
any help?

```
//div[@id="references-body"]//li[not(ancestor::div[@class="otherversion" or 
@class="publishedas"]) and (@class="downfree" or @class="downgate" or 
@class="downnone")]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly locate required elements as

```
//div[@id="references-body"]/ol/li
```

This will return just 49 main `li` elements excluding nested `Other versions` and `Published as` `li` elements

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this only gives me the first 3 rows. I'm using this xpath in the rvest package in r, so it might have something to do with it.. but I'm not sure.